# Is it right to use the word "quotation" in this case?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I'm developing a software application that can automatically send quotations (as a PDF document) to the user's client. So the system sends an email with the text:

> Please find attached the requested quotation for your review.

And, in other parts of the software, there are sentences like this one:

> The quotation was created successfully!

I'm pretty confused if this word *quotation* is the right word to use in this kind of situation. For me, it sounds like *quote*.

Comment: From oxforddictionaries... [**quotation**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quotation) - *A formal statement setting out the estimated cost for a particular job or service*; [**quote**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quote) - *A quotation giving the estimated cost for a particular job or service*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks for the comment! So, is it right to use both words in this case?

Comment: As those dictionary definitions make clear, they can be considered synonyms for this specific sense. In certain contexts it might be acceptable / desirable to actually use *both* synonymous words in the same text, but for your specific context I think it would be poor style. Choose one (it doesn't really matter which) and stick to it consistently.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot! If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: Quotation is fine but Please find attached is not....because the quotation is in the body of the e-mail, isn't it?

Comment: ...apart from any other considerations, you might want to use standard "templates" such as **The %s was created successfully!** (where %s is a "placeholder" replaced at runtime by some passed variable containing *order, quote, refund,* etc.). Software should definitely stick to using the same name every time for any given referent. But this is all "writing advice" - note that I have voted to close your question as "Primarily Opinion-based".

Comment: @Lambie, actually, the quotation is a PDF file!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I'm already doing this! But when creating/deleting/updating quotations, I use the word `quotation` as the variable.

Comment: Whoops, you're right: So: "Please find attached a PDF with the requested quotation for your review." Though, I am not sure of review here. If I don't like it, I can correct it and send it back??

Comment: Yes! Actually, the system sends the e-mail "acting" like the salesperson. A possible reply would be send directly to the salesperson e-mail.

Comment: haha - you obviously don't need *programming* advice from me then! Personally I'd use ***quotation*** throughout (both as the contents of a passed parameter for formatted display, and the name of any class or object *handling* such transaction types). That would probably result in less "false positive" unwanted hits when you do global searches within your project files for the stuff you're interested in. Btw - it's usually *for your **perusal***, not ***review***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Nouns can be derived from verbs by adding a suffix such as '-tion' or '-ment', but many verbs can also be used as nouns without any suffix, such as 'the kick' or 'the quote'.  Both forms are ambiguous in that the noun may mean the object that the verb acts on, or it may mean the entire event.  You are fine to use 'quote' as a noun.  'Quotation' is just fancied up.